# Play framework Scala run job in background

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there any way I can trigger a job from the controller (to not to wait for its completion) and display the message to the user that job will be running in the background?

I have one controller method which takes quite long time to run. So I want to make that run offline and display the message to the user that it will be running in the background.

I tried Action.async as shown below. But the processing of the Future object is still taking more time and getting timed out.

```
def submit(id: Int) = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
    val result = Future {
      //process the data
    }
   result map {
      res =>
      Redirect(routes.testController.list()).flashing(("success", s"Job(s) will be ruuning in background."))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also return a result without waiting for the result of the future in a "fire and forget" way

```
def submit(id: Int) = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>     
    Future {
      //process the data
    }
    Redirect(routes.testController.list()).flashing(("success", s"Job(s) will be running in background."))
}
```

Comment: An alternative is the "actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce {}".  Especially if the background task has anything thread blocking in it, consider the  [custom execution context section](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScheduledTasks#Using-a-CustomExecutionContext) of the scheduled tasks docs.

Comment: "fire and forget" way worked for me. I tried the say way before with Action.async, but it never processed the code inside the Future.  May I know how using Action or Action.async makes the difference here?

Comment: I know this is an old thread. But I am under the impression that the difference between `Action.async` and `Action` is simply that one expects a `Future[T]` and one expects `T`. In the implementation, `Action` is wrapped in a Future so no matter what, it will not block. This may be overly simplified, but that's the way I've always experienced it in practice.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAsync) state:

> By giving a Future[Result] instead of a normal Result, we are able to quickly generate the result without blocking. Play will then serve the result as soon as the promise is redeemed.
>
> **The web client will be blocked** while waiting for the response, but nothing will be blocked on the server, and server resources can be used to serve other clients.

You can configure your client code to use ajax request and display a *Waiting for data* message for some part of the page without blocking the rest of the web page from loading.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the "Futures.timeout" option. It seems to work fine. But I'm not sure its correct way to do it or not.

```
result.withTimeout(20.seconds)(futures).map { res =>
  Redirect(routes.testController.list()).flashing(("success", s"Job(s) will be updated in background."))
}.recover {
  case e: scala.concurrent.TimeoutException =>
    Redirect(routes.testController.list()).flashing(("success", s"Job(s) will be updated in background."))
}
```